# Relay stays on when toggling GPIO pin between LOW / HIGH

Tags: relay

I've got a small 5v relay board ("Ontengfei" JQC-3FF-S-Z) connected to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. When I set the GPIO pin mode to OUTPUT, the relay turns on. When I toggle the GPIO pin between HIGH / LOW, the relay just stays on, it doesn't toggle like I'd expect it to. If I set the GPIO mode to INPUT, the relay turns off. This is really confusing, because I'd expect toggling LOW / HIGH, while the GPIO pin is in OUTPUT mode, to turn the relay on/off.

[image: Relay image]

---

I'm using physical pin 12, wPi 1, BCM 18, depending on your preference. Even though voltage is set to 0 (LOW), the relay is still receiving a signal.

```
$ gpio readall
```

`+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3+--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |  OUT | 0 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |   IN | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 0 | OUT  | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |  OUT | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3+--+---+------+---------+-----+-----+`

### What I've tried

- Adding various resistors in between the GPIO pin and the relay, to reduce the voltage
- Tried physical pin 8 and 12; both exhibited the same behavior
- Added a diode to prevent voltage from being sent from the relay board to the Raspberry Pi. It still worked as above, but didn't fix the issue.
- Connecting it to 3v3 power instead of 5v (same behavior)

Comment: Without detail of the mystery "relay board" who knows? Many (poorly designed) Arduino boards don't work with the Pi.

Comment: I'd guess the relay is `Active Low` because both 0v and 3.3v are not 5v (in my experience, 3v3 sometimes "behaves" like HIGH, and sometimes LOW on a 5v relay - depending on a bunch of factors) - the only flaw to my assumption is that setting the GPIO as input turns the relay off (if it's active LOW as I suspect, then the relay would turn off when the input is "HIGH")

Comment: `When I toggle the GPIO pin between HIGH / LOW` .... how do you know that is what happens? .... the output may already be LOW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16 channel relay module does not respond to write 0/1 (GPIO.HIGH/LOW) commands](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64322/16-channel-relay-module-does-not-respond-to-write-0-1-gpio-high-low-commands)

Comment: @goldilocks no, I meant input to the relay

Comment: @JaromandaX Makes sense -- my bad, I'll delete all that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the relay clearly says it's a 5v relay, it only worked when I connected it to the 3v3 power rail.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the nature and needs of the mistery relay board is hard to help. Nonetheless I'll try. This are steps that I'd try to solve the problem:

- Connect led diode trough some resistor and see if that lights up as expected
- figure out what drives the relay (low or high) signal
- once established that figure out at what voltage relay triggers
- for RPi protection I'd use optocoupler triggering for relays
- Try some other GPIO like 24 or 23 as they don't have alternative functions

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful. It turns out that a low signal actually triggers the relay, not a high signal. I'm still learning. However, the real problem is that 5v was apparently too much for the relay. Connecting it to 3v3 power works just fine. I'm using the `gpio toggle 1` command to switch it on and off. It's working perfectly.